# WDS - PXE Boot can't connect to Deployment Share

Tags: windows-server-2012, deployment, pxe-boot, wds, mdt

Getting the following error message: Connection to the deployment share could not be made. Connection OK. Possible invalid Credentials.

Could this be an error in the "bootstrap.ini" file?
If it is invalid credentials what exactly is this referring to?

I have checked the properties in the Deployment share folder and all seems to be okay.

Comment: Please add more details. Where and when are you getting the message? How is your deployment configured? What boot images and OS images are you deployng? The question as it is now is just too vague to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

The WDS client needs to map the Deployment share folder; the mentioned credentials are the ones used to map that folder.